# Selenium Python Radio Button find_by_xpath Issues

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select a radio button with Selenium Chromedriver in Python. This is the web element I'm working with:

```
<input type="radio" name="frequency" value="3" onchange="displayFields(true);">
```

I've used this syntax for other radio buttons and it works:

```
find_by_xpath("//select[@name='startmonth']/option[@value='8']").click()
```

But when I try to do the same thing for the frequency button, nothing happens and the browser just sits open:

```
find_by_xpath("//select[@name='frequency']/option[@value='3']").click()
```

If I click this button manually on the website, it reveals new fields. Do I need to add **onchange="displayFields(true);** as another line or another option?

Comment: `select[@name='startmonth']/option[@value='8']` would be for selecting an `<option value="8">` in a `<select name="startmonth">`.   Try: `//input[@value='3']`.  Obviously, this would require that input to be the only one input with a value of 3.

Comment: OK. This works, but I have other lines above where the value will sometimes be "3," namely startmonth and startday. I guess I can turn "3" into a variable called "frequency."

Comment: Yep, you can add them together like this, too: `//input[@type='radio'][@name='frequency'][@value='3']`.